# How to take some part of the url as a sub-string using golang in gin package?

Tags: go, substring

In golang I have a url when we hit it with using browser then some code will run. for example url:-

Header:-

```
https://projects.com/id/669461/authenticationKey/0A8BE8D1AFDBC11C700548F72022DA5C
```

***Issue*** :-This is the url and I want to take out some string in the function variable like`number := "0A8BE8D1AFDBC11C700548F72022DA5C"` . How can we do this can anyone help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: where is your Handler `routes` From the end Point You can take This

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Gin, then you should be able to use [its "parameters in path"](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#parameters-in-path) functionality to extract the fragment.

That said, if you're doing this in raw Go, then this should do the trick:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"
  "errors"
  "net/url"
)

const segmentToPluck = 4

func getAuthenticationKey(inputUrl string) (string, error) {
  parsedUrl, err := url.Parse(inputUrl)

  if err != nil {
    return "", err
  }

  split := strings.Split(parsedUrl.Path, "/")

  if len(split) < segmentToPluck + 1 {
    return "", errors.New("unable to find key segment")
  }

  return split[segmentToPluck], nil
}

func main() {
  key, err := getAuthenticationKey("https://projects.com/id/669461/authenticationKey/0A8BE8D1AFDBC11C700548F72022DA5C")

  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  fmt.Println(key)
}
```

The `getAuthenticationKey` function there will select the correct segment from the supplied `inputUrl`.